# Toggle class of clicked object during ajax call with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, object, click

I would like to show a spinner on clicked object when i'm making an Ajax query with jQuery.

Here is what I've tried :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache:false,
        url:'./ajax.php',
        type:'POST',
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            $(this).addClass('ui-ajax-loading')
        },
        complete:function(xhr){
            $(this).removeClass('ui-ajax-loading')
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that $(this) doesn't refer to the clicked object.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Of course not! Why not just do this inside the `click` handler for the object, right before the AJAX, add the class, then in the success of complete method, remove it.

Comment: Ajaxsetup's use is not recommended

Comment: Why not just do this inside the click ? Because I prefer write it just once rather that in my 80 ajax calls. Makes my javascript lighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the context option of your AJAX request if you'd like to change what `this` is inside your `beforeSend` and `complete` functions.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LuP9C/1/

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false,
    url: '/echo/html/',
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        $(this).addClass('ui-ajax-loading');
        $('p').text('Sending...');
    },
    complete: function (xhr) {
        $(this).removeClass('ui-ajax-loading');
        $('p').text('Complete!');
    }
});

$('button').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        context: $(this),
        data: {
            html: 'Hello world!',
            delay: 1
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but i want to change the class of other div . then what can we do ?